# Testing constructor initialization list

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I am working on a test which checks if all class attributes are initialized in a constructor.
My current solution works for non pointer attributes:

```
void CSplitVectorTest::TestConstructorInitialization()
{
    const size_t memorySize = sizeof(CSplitVector);
    char* pBuffer1 = (char*) malloc(memorySize);
    char* pBuffer2 = (char*) malloc(memorySize);
    memset(pBuffer1,'?',memorySize);
    memset(pBuffer2,'-',memorySize);
    new(pBuffer1) CSplitVector;
    new(pBuffer2) CSplitVector;
    const bool bObjectsAreEqual = memcmp(pBuffer1,pBuffer2,memorySize)==0;
    if (!TEST(bObjectsAreEqual))
    {
        COMMENT("Constructor initialization list not complete!");
    }
    free(pBuffer1);
    free(pBuffer2);
}
```

Do you have an idea how could it be improved to test if pointers are initialized?

Comment: Your approach wouldn't work. The compiler may insert padding between the data members.

Comment: @Lol4t0: bytes not occupied by any data member would remain `?` in the 1st buffer and `-` in the 2nd

Comment: What do you mean it does not work for pointers?

Comment: @Marek Ah yes of course. Augmented my answer below (last paragraph).

Comment: For pointers, whenever I can I use smart pointers, otherwise I have the safe pointer of the controlled_vars: http://snapwebsites.org/project/controlled-vars and I use it for all basic data types too (int, char, etc.) This way everything will be initialized no matter what. Especially, if you marked the variables as "need init" then you HAVE to have an initializer in your class. So there is no way you'd miss that.

Comment: @Andrey: Do you think #pragma pack(1) should resolve this issue for test purpose only?

Answer (score 0):

Your test checks whether every byte of the object has been written over by the constructor. As a straight memory check it looks OK, although if the class contains other objects which don't necessarily initialise themselves fully, you may be in trouble.

That said, my main question would be: Is it really an effective test? For example, is it critical that every attribute in the `CSplitVector` class is initialised by the initialisation list? Do you perhaps have some which may not need to be initialised at this point? Also, how about checking whether the attributes are set to values that you'd expect?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of comparing byte by byte, you probably should use the right padding or word size, and test if *any* byte of each word got initialized. That way you will probably get around compiler using padding and constructor leaving uninitialized bytes between padded shorter-than-word fields.

To test the real padding size, shooting from the hip, following code should do it pretty reliably:

```
struct PaddingTest {
  volatile char c; // volatile probably not needed, but will not hurt either
  volatile int i;

  static int getCharPadding() { 
    PaddingTest *t = new PaddingTest;
    int diff = (int)(&(t->i)) - (int)&((t->c));
    delete t;
    return diff;
  }
}
```

Edit: You still need the two objects, but you no longer compare them to each others, you just compare each initialized data to the memset value, and if either object has any change, it means the word got touched (also on the other one, it's just chance that it got initialized to same value you memset).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for mentioned problems, tested it with initialized/not initialized pointers and with different length types.

In test header I added #pragma pack(1) (I am working on gcc)

```
#pragma pack(1)
#include <CSplitVector>
```

Test got a little bit complicated:

```
void CSplitVectorTest::TestConstructorInitialization()
{
    const size_t memorySize = sizeof(CSplitVector);
    char* pBuffer = (char*) malloc(memorySize);
    memset(pBuffer,'?',memorySize);
    CSplitVector* pSplitVector = new(pBuffer) CSplitVector;

    // find pointers for all '?'
    QList<char*> aFound;
    char* pFoundChar = (char*) memchr(pBuffer,'?',memorySize);
    while (pFoundChar)
    {
        aFound.append(pFoundChar);
        char* pStartFrom = pFoundChar+1;
        pFoundChar = (char*) memchr(pStartFrom,'?',memorySize-(int)(pStartFrom-pBuffer));
    }
    // if there are any '?'....
    if (aFound.count())
    {
        // allocate the same area with '-'...
        pSplitVector->~CSplitVector();
        memset(pBuffer,'-',memorySize);
        pSplitVector = new(pBuffer) CSplitVector;
        // and check if places found before contain '-'
        while (aFound.count())
        {
            pFoundChar = aFound.takeFirst();
            if (*pFoundChar=='-')
            {
                // if yes then class has uninitialized attribute
                TEST_FAILED("Constructor initialization list not complete!");
                pSplitVector->~CSplitVector();
                free(pBuffer);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    // if no then all attributes are initialized
    pSplitVector->~CSplitVector();
    free(pBuffer);
    TEST(true);
}
```

Feel free to point any flaws in this solution.